# Is the following JQuery exploitable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

My company runs an automated static analysis tool and the following code snippet was marked as exploitable for XSS.

```js
$(`${foo} ${location.hash}:not(.match)`);
```

`foo` is always an id selector like `#id`.  Because the selector is always prefixed, I don't believe that is exploitable.

Could anyone come up with an exploit example? A value for location.hash where Javascript execution is possible.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: That code as posted in the question doesn't do anything anyway, other than create a jQuery object that's ignored.

Comment: it is no more exploitable than $(foo + " " + location.hash + ":not(.match)") is. It'd be far more useful to look into what checks/rules the snippet crossed in the analysis tool. If it's just throwing up a warning any time location.hash is used, for example, such a warning becomes just that

Comment: I think the alert is just indicating that you have user-controllable input directly used as a parameter to the $ function. If location.hash was the first piece of the argument you could use something like ```<img/src/onerror=alert()><!--``` to get code execution. But as you have the foo prefix, I don't think it's a problem.
The problem is I am not that familiar with JQuery so I wanted to make sure before asking for an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official answer https://github.com/jquery/jquery/discussions/4899. In summary, jQuery >=1.9 requires input resulting in creating new elements to start with <, possibly preceded by some whitespace. Therefore, the before-mentioned construction is not vulnerable to XSS.